# If $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=2$, then $(a^2+bc)(b^2+ca)(c^2+ab)\leq 1$

Tags: inequality, arithmetic

Prove that if $a,b$ and $c$ are non negative real numbers such that $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=2$, then we have $$(a^2+bc)(b^2+ca)(c^2+ab)\leq 1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove the inequality
$$4(a^2+bc)(b^2+ca)(c^2+ab)\le (a+b)^2(b+c)^2(c+a)^2.$$Without loss of generality, assume  that $a\ge b\ge c$. Since

$$a^2+bc\le (a+c)^2$$

and
$$4(b^2+ca)(c^2+ab)\le (b^2+ca+c^2+ab)^2,$$
it suffices to show that
$$b^2+c^2+ab+ac\le (a+b)(b+c).$$
This inequality is equivalent to $c(a-b)\le 0$, which is clearly true.

Solution 2: this inequality is equivalent to
$$(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2+4bc\sum bc(b+c)+8a^2b^2c^2\ge 0.$$